# Why isn't my UI updating accordingly after I set state?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an app where I need to allow the user to highlight parts of text that I'm getting from an API and saving to state. Currently I have the unique value keys of each verse of the text being saved in a state value (highlightID) when clicked. A action bar slides up and they are able to select a color to highlight the selection with. Once highlighted the values are saved to a state variable (permHighlights) and then passed to firestore to be stored in a database. The problem arises when I've been trying to create a delete function. I've tried many variations but i can't get the highlights to delete, update state and firestore and the UI consistently. It either work or it'll delete the highlight and then the last one or a random middle highlight will return.

This is the function that I'm currently using to delete the docs from firestore and update state.

```
const deletePermHighlight = () => {
    highlightID.forEach((highlightid) => {
      let newHighlights = [...permHighlight];
      console.log(permHighlight);
      const selectedHighlight = newHighlights.find(
        (e) => e.versePK === highlightid
      );
      if (selectedHighlight) {
        console.log("selectedHighlight:" + selectedHighlight);
        deleteDoc(doc(db, "biblehighlights", selectedHighlight.id))
          .then(() => {
            const indexOfHighlight = newHighlights.findIndex(
              (e) => e.versePK === highlightid
            );
            console.log("this is the indexof the highlight" + indexOfHighlight);
            newHighlights.splice(indexOfHighlight, 1);
            console.log("this is the new array" + newHighlights);
            setPermHightlight(newHighlights);
          })
          .catch((e) => console.log(e));
      }
    });
    getHighlights();
  };
```

this is the function I'm using to get the highlights from the database and I've called at the end. My thinking was to refresh the UI... which clearly is incorrect.

```
  const getHighlights = async () => {
    getDocs(q)
      .then((querySnapshot) => {
        const newData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          ...doc.data(),
          id: doc.id,
        }));
        setPermHightlight(newData);
      })
      .then(console.log(permHighlight))
      .then(console.log("gothighlights"))
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  };
```

any insight on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.